# Magento 1 shopping cart: product list empty, but there is products

Tags: product, cart, shopping, list

When I open shopping cart, the product list seems to be empty; however there is products, infact the total show the price. Any suggesion?

Thank youenter image description here

Magento 1.9.4.5

[image]

Comment: Have you check console and error log files?

Comment: I found these errors:

[30-Jul-2020 13:44:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php on line 230
[30-Jul-2020 13:50:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  scandir(/home/mdpoyzba/public_html/./pkginfo): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php on line 243
[30-Jul-2020 13:50:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php on line 243

Comment: [30-Jul-2020 14:24:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setLayer() on boolean in /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php:134
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
#1 /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))

Comment: #2 /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('ambrands/catalo...', 'ambrands.navlef...')
#3 /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('ambrands/catalo...', 'ambrands.navlef...')
#4 /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))

Comment: #5 /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.p in /home/mdpoyzba/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php on line 134

Comment: The issue into this one (Smartwave_All) so disable this extension and then check.